# preg_match in Javascript and finding specific variables

Tags: javascript, php, preg-match, match

I'm trying to match something to the end of a cs go inspect link

```
steam://rungame/730/76561202255233023/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20S76561198261551396A6723850108D7097851293459665429
```

Specifically the `S76561198261551396A6723850108D7097851293459665429` where the letters `S`, `A`, and `D` are constant.

<sub>Added from comments:</sub>
I got this `/([SM])(\d+)A(\d+)D(\d+)$/` from another source, but honestly I'm just confused about the whole process.

Also, is there an efficient way to get the integers following these letters without just breaking apart the string?

Comment: @MartinHeralecký I got this "/([SM])(\d+)A(\d+)D(\d+)$/" from another source, but honestly I'm just confused about the whole process. I'd like to learn how it works.

Comment: Do you want to do this in PHP or JavaScript? The RegEx you posted in the comment should work. [See here why and how](https://regex101.com/r/rF3nF1/1)

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that there are *many* web-sites which will allow you to paste-in some data, then paste-in a regular expression, and "try it out."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a rather simplified version of what you could do:

```
$str = 'steam://rungame/730/76561202255233023/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20S76561198261551396A6723850108D7097851293459665429)';
$pattern = '/S(\d*)A(\d*)D(\d*)/';

preg_match($pattern, $str, $matches);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($matches);
```

`$matches` will return this array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => S76561198261551396A6723850108D7097851293459665429
    [1] => 76561198261551396
    [2] => 6723850108
    [3] => 7097851293459665429
)
```

The last three elements of the array are the numbers you're looking for.